# can't resolve Cannot find module 'rxjs' within typescript/webpack

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, rxjs, es6-modules

I've got a problem to load `rxjs` into a simple webpack setup (without angular). I'm running:

```
./node_modules/.bin/webpack --config webpack.config.js --watch
```

to start webpack. The only file with the app, `src/app.ts`, starts with:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
```

and this line is highlighted in VSCode and in webpack console with this error:

```
Cannot find module 'rxjs'.
```

But the overall output works fine. Just this console error.

`tsconfig.json`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
         "target": "es2015"
    },
    "files": [
        "src/app.ts"
    ]
}
```

`webpack.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: "./src/app.ts",
    output: {
        filename: "dist/bundle.js"
    },
    resolve: {
        // Add '.ts' and '.tsx' as a resolvable extension.
        extensions: [".webpack.js", ".web.js", ".ts", ".tsx", ".js"]
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            // all files with a '.ts' or '.tsx' extension will be handled by 'ts-loader'
            { test: /\.ts?$/, loader: "ts-loader" }
        ]
    }
}
```

`package.json` (everything installed properly):

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "./node_modules/.bin/webpack --config webpack.config.js --watch"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "ts-loader": "^2.1.0",
    "typescript": "^2.3.4",
    "webpack": "^2.6.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.4.5"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.0"
  }
}
```

I can't find the reason for why can't ts/webpack resolve where is `rxjs`

Answer (score 20):

You should change default module resolution strategy from Classic to Node. In order to do this, change your `tsconfig.json` file:

```
{
    ...
    "compilerOptions": {
        ....
        "moduleResolution": "node"
    }
}
```

See documentation on [Module Resolution](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#node)

Comment: Well I don't know about OP but you saved me some hours :D Thanks!

Comment: It worked for me with `"module": "commonjs"` and updated VSCode to the latest version. But if it helped someone - it's good :)

Answer (score 16):

to ionic

simple use this command in order to delete the plugin

```
npm uninstall --save rxjs

npm uninstall --save rxjs-compat
```

and then run this to reinstall

```
npm install --save rxjs

npm install --save rxjs-compat
```

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue when I tried building with nestjs from scratch,
this should solve your problem

`npm install rxjs`

and if that doesn’t, try this:

delete node_modules and package-lock.json
`rm -rf node_modules rm -f package-lock.json`

clean npm cache
`npm cache clean --force`

try reinstalling
`npm install`

Answer (score 0):

You must add `node_modules` to your webpack resolve.modules config:

```
 resolve: {
    modules: [
      "node_modules",
      path.resolve(__dirname, "app")
    ],
    extensions: [".js", ".json", ".jsx", ".css"],
 }
```

more info on https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/

Comment: this doesn't make much sense to me; the [docs](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-modules) say that `resolve.modules` defaults to `"node_modules"`, so I don't have to add it, I just don't change it. And I don't have to add `"app"` there, because why?